# WHMCS Suddenly stopped working

Tags: linux, centos, cpanel, whmcs, whmcs-invoice-template

I am using WHMCS lifetime license but it suddenly stopped working now it's showing could not connect to database which seems false to me..

My mysql server is up i have tested same db credentials in a new connectivity file . Everything is working perfectly.

Though WHMCS staff is saying it's db issue.. Kinda joke for me..

If anyone else is facing same issue. Please help thanks.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/g862bd

http://prntscr.com/g862iq

However as per  my custom mysqli connectivity file  database is connected and there are many other websites on same server all are connected to mysql and working only this whmcs is causing issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the following file in the root directory of your WHMCS installation as test_db_configuration.php:

```
<?php
include('configuration.php');

try{
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$db_host.";dbname=".$db_name, $db_username, $db_password);
    echo 'Connected to the MySQL server.';
}
catch(PDOException $ex){
    echo 'Unable to connect: <strong>'. $ex->getMessage();'</strong>';
}
```

Save the file and open https://your-client-area/test_db_configuration.php. If it works,  you will see the text `Connected to the MySQL server.` in your browser. Otherwise, the cause will be shown.

If the script is unable to connect, check if there are any errors found in the database log. Usually they are in /var/lib/mysql/`hostname`.err or in /var/log/mysql. If no error is to be found, you can check if error logging is enabled in MySQL or configure your my.cnf to log them in the desired location.

Comment: Database is already working as i mentioned in my post. I am able to connect it directly

Comment: If it is working, we can look further into this problem. Since the script uses the exact same data as WHMCS does, we do know that the configuration is not the issue.

Did you check the MySQL logs for errors (and enabled this)? It might give you some clues. Did you also enable the debug mode for WHMCS? You can do so by adding the following to `configuration.php`: `$display_errors = true;`